# Delete a column without header in excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, pivot

Is there any possible way to delete a column without header in excel file using python? I need to delete this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFfmo.png)header less column from my data set using python

Comment: Sure. How was the excel file generated by the way? Was it with pandas: `pd.to_excel()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to columns by numbers using `.iloc[]` method.
Or in this particular case, you just need `df = pandas.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=0)` with index and `df.to_excel("file.xlsx", index=False)` without index, that's all.
In one line, it will be:

```py
pandas.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=0).to_excel("file.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: It gives me a output as none. I need to delete a header less column in a particular work sheet

Comment: There is no output from this line of code. It reads your excel file (which screenshot you attached) and writes this table without the first column replacing the initial file on your disc. If you want to read a particular sheet from the Excel file, add the corresponding parameter to pandas.read_excel() method.